# How can I investigate slow application performance?

Tags: nvidia, libreoffice, gui, performance

I am running LibreOffice Calc 5.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and its performance is catastrophically slow.

I have scoured the forum pool for possible answers, and have tried every option available to me:

- Turn off Java Runtime
- Change object memory allowance
- Turned on/off OpenCL
- Turned on/off OpenGL
- Turned on/off antialiasing
- Tried every proprietary, tested and open source nVidia driver available
- Used local instead of samba shared files
- Unmounted all network shares
- Disconnected from network entirely
- Moved to the lightweight xfce4 window manager

LibreOffice remains crippled and unusable. It will scroll, will occasionally grey out waiting. Copying and pasting cell formulas, insanely slow, greyouts constantly. This is on a LO native spreadsheet with only one sheet and only as many entries as can be seen at one time.

I have installed gnome-boxes on the same machine, installed Windows 7 inside that. I have installed LO 5.2 inside *that*, and opened the same spreadsheet. Interactivity is smooth and realtime like it should be, on the same machine, inside a virtual machine.

I am running a HP workstation laptop: nVidia FX880M; Intel Core i7 Q 820 1.73GHz in hyperthreading mode (8 HT cores); 32 GB RAM.

I don't know that anyone has the answer other than just playing with settings and hoping. I am not a developer of Linux kernels nor of LibreOffice but I do code. What tools are available to discover what on earth is taking so long in Lo under Ubuntu that makes it so unfathomably slow? How can I use something more than guesswork to debug what is up with this install, my machine, etc.?

**Edit:** Curiously, an upgrade to 16.04 LTS has completely solved the issue. Doesn't explain why but clearly there is some difference between the two that can account for the issue.

Comment: Have you checked that you're running the latest/correct nVidia graphics driver? There's been a lot of discussion about using nVidia software vs other drivers here in the forum. You can search for nVidia and HP and see what pops up. Cheers, Al

Comment: There is a [debug wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/How_to_debug), also, asking at [ask-libreoffice](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/How_to_debug) won't hurt. LB 5.2 is very new, and likely has not been tested on 14.04 at all, so problems should be expected.

Comment: @heynnema  Yes for this card there is a 304.131 from nvidia-304 and nvidia-304-updates; there is a 340.96 from nvidia-340 and nvidia-340-updates; and there is the X.Org X server - Nouveau  driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau . nVidia website lists the 340.96 as the latest driver available.